# restricted to do something? from?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, verbs, negation

I have a question.

Restrict to do something and restrict from doing something have the same meaning?

for example,

I am restricted to smoke one cigarette one day 
I am restricted from smoking one cigarette one day.

Are those sentences the same meaning or not?

I just had an argument with my colleague over this topic.

I think restricted to do something and restricted from doing something 
are different. please help.

Answer (score 7):

These are quite different.

In the first example, **to** is making restricted mean something like *limited*:

> I am restricted to smoking one cigarette per day.

This means:

I am *limited* to smoking one cigarette per day.

The other example, **from** is quite different:

> I am restricted from smoking one cigarette per day.

This would literally mean the exact opposite:

> I am not allowed to smoke one cigarette per day.

The general understanding is that it's saying you can not smoke cigarettes at all but it could also be interpreted as being allowed to smoke two or more cigarettes, but not just one.

I'd argue that, in AmE, people wouldn't generally use this form.

Comment: OP please note above that it's "restricted to SMOKING,  not "restricted to SMOKE".  But you could say "...allowed to smoke..."